# Run command inside all folders and sub folders with specific extension

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

Currently, I'm trying run a command on my linux server (Ubuntu 16.04) to reencode all .mp4 files. But I have a lot of files inside folders and subfolders, and I'm going to waste a lot of time running these commands manually

Here is my script:

```
for D in ./*; do
    if [ -d "$D" ]; then
        cd "$D"
        for i in *.mp4; do
            ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec copy -acodec copy -shortest -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:eng "${i%.*}.mp4"
        done
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '*.mp4'
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find` for this.  It handles sub-directory recursion for you.  Like so:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -codec copy -acodec copy -shortest -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:eng {}  \; -print
```

- `find` will automatically process the current directory and all sub-directories
- `-type f`: to search only files
- `-name "*.mp4": only files with mp4 extension
- `-exec COMMAND {} \;`: execute that command on all found files.  `{}` will be replaced by the file name of each file.  `\;` to end the command.
- `-print`: will print which file was processed

---

As far as your code goes, there is a possibility that a directory will not have any "*.mp4" files, hence the `no such file or directory, stat '*.mp4'` error when you hit such a directory.

Comment: Hello, how can I get filename using `{}` without extension?

Comment: Sometimes, `.mp4` should be converted to `.mkv`. And If I put `{}.mkv` returns `{filename}.mp4.mkv`

Comment: You can use a combination of basename and dirname. But you can only use {} once. I would write a script that accepts the file name from {}, calculate the new file name, and call FFmpeg. Then use that script in the find -exec

Comment: While, if needed, a script that calculates a new file name is a good idea, as a point of clarification, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) _requires_ that `find` support, under some conditions, multiple uses of `{}` in one command.  GNU `find` supports multiple uses of `{}` under wider conditions than required by POSIX.  As the answer it currently written, the code satisfies the POSIX conditions for multiple uses of `{}`.  A form such as `{}.mkv`, however, would require GNU `find` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Example (no effect, only do `echo ...`):

```
$ find \
  . \
  -type f \
  -name '*.mp4' \
  -exec sh -c '
    for src in "$@"; do
      dst="${src%.*}.mkv"
      echo ffmpeg ... "$src" ... "$dst"
    done
  ' sh {} + \
  -print \
;
```

You must replace `echo ffmpeg ... "$src" ... "$dst"` with your command-line for production use. You can remove `-print` from the example.